# How could I ignore the base path in nginx when I want to proxy to Flask?

Tags: proxy, routing, nginx

I wrote a program in Flask, I release it in Nginx server, there are other servers in this Nginx, so I add this code in the config file:

```
location ^~ /flask {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 }
```

I want to visit Flask app like this

```
http://localhost/flask
```

then it will visit my application method which route is `@app.route('/')`, but its response is “404 error”. I know it visits method which is  `@app.route('/flask')`, I don't expect to add config in Python file, Is there any solution for this issue?

I expect I will solve it by modifying config of Nginx. How should I do it?

Comment: You're using a proxy like you would a CName or A record in a DNS configuration. Try the python config change.